# Primefaces data table paginator

Tags: primefaces

In my main page i have a datatable with 10 paginators at the bottom,if i select the 5th page and edit the records and saving the details.After saving the details it comes to main page.The problem is after saving and come back to main page the data table displaying paginator position from 01.I want to  display my data table paginator at 5th position after edit and saving the details and coming back to main page.Can any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=25399

Comment: Iam using spring web flow.I have different flows like employee,dashboard etc.In every flow i have data table with paginators.i have problem with backing bean concept when i call an ajax from one data table flow it is effecting remaining flow also.For example if iam in employee flow and change the paginator position from 1 to 7 in data table it is also effecting in dashboard flow .i.e datatable paginator position automatically changes to 7.Please help me.

Comment: you can try storing your paginator page in a bean and then you can set the paginator back to that page with something like this `PF('yourTable').paginator.setPage(#{yourBean.paginatorPage})` , where `yourTable` is the value of the `widgetVar` property of your table